# Im getting an error message dns

Tags: google-chrome, dns, reset

I'm trying to search this site interstore365. I purchased something from it but now this is the message I get.
interstore365.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
RELOAD
I'm new to this but I think i reset the correct flag to default. I have a lg kv8 android phone. Please help

Comment: Hi. This doesn't look like a programming question. I think you are on the wrong network here.

Comment: I'm very new to this can u tell me where i should look to find my answer please

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that the website took itself down. They also removed all of their social media. They are fraudulent. File a chargeback with your bank or credit card company. Also check for multiple charges from the company!